# How to combine multiple azure artifacts to one web deploy in the release process

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, webdeploy

I have a website which is the combination of 3 separate artifacts.

1. The base files for Sitecore (a CMS, best practice is to keep it separate from your own code repo), this artifact is just files
2. The custom logic for the web site (.net) which is compiled into a web deploy package
3. An additional module that we only release to the dev server. This artifact is just files (2 dll's and a config file)

[image]

At the moment to deploy to our dev server I have 3 IIS Web App Deploy tasks to release to IIS on a VM. The first removes the existing files and publishes one artifact and the next 2 just publish the additional artifacts.

However this feels really wrong and that it should all be done in one task. It's also not particularly fast having 3 separate processes to deploy files.

[image]

How can I set this up better? Speed is a big concern as this would currently take the site out for about 10 minutes while the deploy happens.

Comment: With the IIS Web APP deploy task we cannot achieve that, however you can try to write a script to deploy them together, and just run a command line/bash/PowerShell task to run the script.

Comment: Hi,Tim Griffiths  How is your issue progressing?Is the following explanation helpful?If you have any question,please kindly let me know.

Comment: Not really, so far it seems like it can't be done

Answer (score 1):

> combine multiple azure artifacts to one web deploy task in the release

For this issue,I think one 'IIS web app deploy' task could not achieve this feature.

I test with the wildcard provided by default: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\*.zip`

Then I get this error:

[image]

From the error message ,it presents that we can not select more than on package with the search pattern, I think this could be due to the limitation of 'IIS web app deploy' task, only one artifact can be specified in an 'IIS web app deploy' task. At present, to deploy multiple artifacts can only be achieved through multiple deploy tasks.

You can make your request to the IIS Web Application Deployment task in [git hub](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues).